# British Flag theorem generalized and inspired from British Flag theorem

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[British Flag theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem): Let $P$ be a point in the plane, let $ABCD$ be a rectangle in the plane then:

$$PA^2+PC^2=PB^2+PD^2$$

**Generalization:** Let $ABCD$ be a rectangle in a plane, Let $P$ be a point in the Euclidean three-space, then:

$$PA^2+PC^2=PB^2+PD^2$$

**Define two directly similar cuboids:** Let $ABCDEFGH$ and $A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1F_1G_1H_1$ be two directly similar cuboids if $ABCDEFGH$ and $A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1F_1G_1H_1$ are two cuboids and:

$$\frac{AB}{A_1B_1}=\frac{BC}{B_1C_1}=\frac{AE}{A_1E_1}$$

**Example:** Two [cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube) are two directly similar [cuboids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid).

<strike>**Generalization:**</strike> **Inspiration from British Flag theorem**: Let $ABCDEFGH$ and $A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1F_1G_1H_1$ be two directly similar [cuboids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboid) in Euclidean three-space, then:

> $$AA_1^2+CC_1^2+FF_1^2+HH_1^2=BB_1^2+DD_1^2+EE_1^2+GG_1^2$$

**My question:** The result is holds in [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) ?

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a generalization since you aren't even using a point $P$ anymore.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "two directly similar cuboids"?

Comment: In the British flag theorem there is only one rectangle. In your "generalization" why are there two cuboids? The natural generalization of the British flag theorem to three dimensions is for a cuboid $ABCDEFGH$ and a point $P$ we have $PA^2+PG^2 = PB^2+PH^2 = PC^2+PE^2 = PD^2+PF^2$.

Comment: Do you know if your generalization is true in two dimensions, i.e. for two rectangles $A_1B_1C_1D_1$ and $A_2B_2C_2D_2$ in the plane, is $A_1A_2^2 + C_1C_2^2 = B_1B_2^2 + D_1D_2^2$?

Comment: What do you consider to be a cuboid? The special case you added under `remarks` holds true only if $ABCD$ is a rectangle, but the faces of a generic cuboid are not necessarily rectangles.

Comment: @Rahul yes, it is true. See: Stan Dolan (2015). Student Problems. The Mathematical Gazette, 99, pp 554-556. doi:10.1017/mag.2015.108.

https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-gazette/article/student-problems/B7DA02AB6D31CB8FC6DD277A199A733E

Answer (score 2):

The following does not prove (or disprove) your conjecture. Instead, it only shows that it is *not* a generalization of the British Flag theorem, because it holds true in the degenerate case of a single point and an arbitrary quadrilateral, while the British Flag theorem only holds for rectangles.

Consider a cuboid $ABCDEFGH$ with congruent faces $ABCD$ and $EFGH$ (which are not necessarily rectangles). Flatten this cuboid such that at the limit $ABCD \equiv EFGH$. Now shrink the directly similar cuboid $A_1B_1C_1D_1E_1F_1G_1H_1$ down to a single limit point $P$.

Then the relation:

$$AA_1^2+CC_1^2+FF_1^2+HH_1^2=BB_1^2+DD_1^2+EE_1^2+GG_1^2$$

becomes:

$$PA^2+PC^2+PB^2+PD^2=PB^2+PD^2+PA^2+PC^2$$

which is always true.

In contrast, the British Flag theorem only holds true for $ABCD$ rectangles, and a variation thereof exists for parallelograms, but none such for arbitrary quadrilaterals.